# query about accessing the ringtone sync functionality of iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, synchronization

i came across [this](http://www.tuaw.com/2007/09/01/iphone-101-adding-custom-ringtones-to-your-contacts/) post where Reader Comment #16 mentions: **"The ringtone syncing functionality is ALREADY inside the iPhone, it just needs to be accessed"**

I understand that you can transfer your music files,ringtones, videos all by syncing your iphone with iTunes.

But what does the above mentioned statement imply?

I am currently working on a project which needs to assign customized ringtones to contacts, if a sync feature is available via programming, it would be really useful to me.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syncing is not accessible via SDK, thats what i conclude after searching through Google. But I do hope someone proves me wrong :)